# Display block after some action (saved node)

Tags: blocks, rules

I want to display block after an action. My user will create new content (node). After he save it, the content is shown with a specific block (only once, no further).

I was looking on trigger module, but I do not see this option.

I am using Drupal 6

Thank you for help!

Comment: why dont you try https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7 ?

Comment: Well, i am not good programmer. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: It sounds like you have a very specific feature in mind, I doubt you'll find a pre-built module which will let you achieve it.

Comment: Perhaps some trick solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/) + [Rules Bonus Pack](https://www.drupal.org/project/rb) for this. The Rules Bonus Pack module has actions for enabling and disabling blocks upon a certain event (e.g. save a node). See [this screencast](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/manage-special-case-block-visibility-with-rules/2011-06-24) for an explanation.

*Note; Rules Bonus Pack is a testing ground for new functionality for the Rules module, so test thoroughly. However, the linked screencast above was published in 2011, so perhaps the code had some test mileage already.*

Comment: Its nice, but "block feature" is only for D7. I am using D6.

Comment: Is there some other way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Not that I know of. I think your easiest way to do this is either code yourself (comment by Pan Chrono) or take a look at the Blocks part of the Rules Bonus Pack D7 module and port that back to the D6 version of that same module.

Comment: I am bad with that. I was hoping for an easier and cleaner solution. Anyway, thank you for your time!